# Как правильно указать Vector при вызове Instantiate?

Tags: c#, unity3d, vector

Я хочу спавнить объекты и указывать их местоположение. Я попробовала просто указать вектора, но мне выдаёт ошибку. Пожалуйста подскажите, как это правильно делать.

Вот код:

```
public class Script : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject spheres;

    void Start () {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Instantiate(spheres);
        }
    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> Assets/Script.cs(14,4): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(UnityEngine.Object, UnityEngine.Transform)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Assets/Script.cs(14,4): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(UnityEngine.Object, UnityEngine.Transform)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Спасибо, больше не надо, я решила эту проблему

Comment: Если решила сама, стоит либо добавить свой ответ, с описанием в чем была проблема и как решили, либо удалить вопрос